# import networkx without packages

Tags: python

i have urged python with NetworkX But i have a problem when i open the console and run

```
adrian@adrian-G551JW:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> print dir(nx)
['DiGraph', 'Graph', 'GraphMLReader', 'GraphMLWriter' ... ]
```

but when I change the directory example

```
adrian@adrian-G551JW:~/Documentos/python$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> print dir(nx)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

networkx not have any package. ¿why?

Comment: And did you *install* the NetworkX? How did you install it?

Comment: Did you create `networkx.py` file in second directory ? if yes then now you inport this file instead of expected module. Try `print(nx.__file__)`.

Comment: @Furas thanks that was the problem.